# Is there a way to get the error code from THTTPClient/WinHTTP without handling the error string?

Tags: delphi

I try to get the [winhttp error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/error-messages) from the `ENetHTTPClientException` exception thrown by `THTTPClient`.

```
Class name:    ENetHTTPClientException
Message:       Error sending data: (12002) Das Zeitlimit für den Vorgang wurde erreicht
Unit name:     System.Net.HttpClient
```

This is my example code:

```
var
  http: THTTPClient;
  request, response: TStringStream;
  httpresponse: IHTTPResponse;
  lasterror: Cardinal;
begin
  http := THTTPClient.Create;
  request := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  response := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    try
      httpresponse := http.Post('url that runs into timeout', request, response);
    except
      on E: ENetHTTPClientException do begin
        lasterror := GetLastError; // I expect 12002 for the timeout, but it's actually 0.
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(lasterror));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    response.Free;
    request.Free;
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`lasterror` always seems to be 0.

This is how the exception is handled:

```
function TWinHTTPClient.HandleExecuteError(AErrorMsg: PResStringRec; const ARequest: THTTPRequest): TWinHTTPClient.TExecutionResult;
var
  LastError: Cardinal;
begin
  LastError := GetLastError;
  case LastError of
    ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE:
      if (SecureFailureReasons <> [THTTPSecureFailureReason.SecurityChannelError]) and
         not TWinHTTPRequest(ARequest).FServerCertificateAccepted then
        Exit(TExecutionResult.ServerCertificateInvalid)
      else
        raise ENetHTTPClientException.CreateResFmt(AErrorMsg, [LastError, SysErrorMessage(LastError, TWinHttpLib.Handle)]);
    ERROR_WINHTTP_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED:
      Exit(TExecutionResult.ClientCertificateNeeded);
    ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST:
      Exit(TExecutionResult.Retry);
    else
      if (LastError = ERROR_WINHTTP_OPERATION_CANCELLED) and
         (SecureFailureReasons = [THTTPSecureFailureReason.CertNotAccepted]) then
        raise ENetHTTPCertificateException.CreateRes(@SNetHttpServerCertificateNotAccepted)
      else
      if (LastError = ERROR_WINHTTP_OPERATION_CANCELLED) or TWinHTTPRequest(ARequest).FCancelled then
        Exit(TExecutionResult.Success)
      else
        raise ENetHTTPClientException.CreateResFmt(AErrorMsg, [LastError, SysErrorMessage(LastError, TWinHttpLib.Handle)]);
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to get the error code from THTTPClient/WinHTTP without handling the error string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the error code from THTTPClient/WinHTTP without handling the error string?

Unfortunately, no.

You can't rely on `GetLastError()` maintaining its original value during an exception raise.  The act of raising, catching, and dispatching the exception may erase the original error code, as you have noticed.

According to the code you quoted, the error code is not being passed to the exception as anything other than a parameter for format strings for the `Message` property. It is not being stored anywhere else.

So, your only option is to parse the exception's `Message` property. However, since the error code is being formatted inside of parenthesis, it should be very easy to find and extract.

Also note that `ENetHTTPCertificateException` is one of the possible exceptions. It is not derived from `ENetHTTPClientException`, so you will have to handle it separately.  Which you would have to do anyway, as its `Message` doesn't have the error code in it.